# Ограничение рерусров контейнера на aws ecs (Ошибка "Java heap space" при сортировке)

Tags: java, docker, amazon-web-services

Разворачиваю на **AWS ECS** контейнеры и пробую настроить оптимальную структуру. Для тестирования запустил контейнер с сортировкой на 45млн элементов и получил ошибку **Java heap space**. 40млн сортируются нормально. При этом загрузка оперативной памяти инстанса не подымается выше 30процентов. На том же инстансе запустил второй таск: и 2 таска могут одновременно сортировать по 40млн элементов. При создании **Task defenition** пробовал изменять **memory reservation** - эффекта 0. Пробовал указывать `-Xms<size> и -Xmx<size>` эффекта ноль.

Но когда я запустил **теже самые таски** на инстансе помощнее - они оба уже сортируют по 60мнл элементов одновременно без каких либо доп настроек.
Насколько я понимаю: **memoryReservation** - это параметр при котором под контейнер резервируется оперативная память сервера, но это не граничный лимит и контейнер может занять всю свободную оперативную память, если появится такая необходимость.
Как выделить ресурсы под контейнер чтобы он один мог использовать все свободные ресурсы нстанса?
Или есть какоето обоснование при котором есть смысл реально запускать 2 одинаковых контейнера вместо одного?
Спасибо.